# Driving on bedrock damages tracked machinery?

Tags: bulldozer, grouser-shoes

I’ve heard that driving on bedrock can damage steel-tracked machines like excavators and bulldozers. Something about bare rock being worse than driving on soil, asphalt, or gravel.

Is that true and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Soil, asphalt and gravel are more resilient than bare rock, so they offer the tracks some damping against the shock of movement across the ground.

But rock offers none, except possibly softer rocks like sandstone.

Comment: Resilient is good for the ground, but the fact that they compress and deform more than the treads is good for the treads. And lots of soil deforms and does not spring back, so it is not particularly resilient.

Comment: @JonCuster - If soil, asphalt, or gravel springs back any more than rock, it is *more resilient*.  Doesn't have to be *greatly* resilient to be *more* resilient. Just saying.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 - it is a bit of a picky language issue, for sure. I would say the rock is significantly more resilient than other surfaces  since you can't see any remaining deformation after the machine goes over it. Yet it did deform under stress.

Comment: Even if the ground does not spring back, it still adsorbs some of the shock.